# Optimizing ViT-B-16 Transformer Training: How to Accelerate Training Time

Tags: computer-vision

I am attempting to fine-tune the ViT-B-16 transformer on the ImageNet and SUN397 datasets. However, it currently requires at least 2 days to run for 15 epochs, and I also need to fine-tune the hyperparameters. I am utilizing 4 GPUs with 40 GB of memory and a batch size of 512. Is there any potential way to accelerate the training time or identify hyperparameters that won't take as much time?